# camel unmarshal Json into a parameter on a bean's method

Tags: parameters, apache-camel, unmarshalling

I'm having a really bad time unmarshalling the body of a message into a pojo at invocation time.

I've got a very simple route being defined with a unmarshalling of the body into my custom pojo:

```
    <dataFormats>
        <json id="json" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.trumin.domain.model.result.Result" />
    </dataFormats>


    <camel:route>
        <camel:from
            uri="activemq:topic:result?clientId=sswric_01&amp;durableSubscriptionName=sendSMSWhenResultIsCalculated" />
        <marshal ref="json" />
        <bean beanType="com.trumin.communications.sms.TimeResultSMSSender"
            method="sendTextToUserAfterTimeResultBeingSaved(${body})" />
    </camel:route>
</camelContext>
```

the method I'm trying to invoke here:

```
sendTextToUserAfterTimeResultBeingSaved(Result r);
```

receives a param of type Result as defined in the json data format and it is not being invoked when the message gets delivered.

If I modify the method signature to accept a String instead of a Result:

```
sendTextToUserAfterTimeResultBeingSaved(String s);
```

then it gets invoked and the string contains the result json representation.

Is there any way in which what I'm trying to achieve works?

I've also tried removing the (${body}) specification from the route, I've tried other unmarshal libraries, I've tried reading all the camel tutorials and links to parameter binding, I've read most of the camel in action chapters regarding this but still can't find my answer.

Comment: I think you need to change marshal for unmarshal in your route. (unless that was a typo when typing the question!) As I understand it you're sending a JSON string to the activemq topic and you want a Result object to arrive at the method?

Answer (score 0):

In the end... This fixed it:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:json id="jsonToResult" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.trumin.domain.model.result.Result" />
    </camel:dataFormats>


    <camel:route>
        <camel:from
            uri="activemq:topic:result?clientId=sswric_01&amp;durableSubscriptionName=sendSMSWhenResultIsCalculated" />
        <camel:unmarshal ref="jsonToResult" />
        <camel:bean beanType="com.trumin.communications.sms.TimeResultSMSSender"
            method="sendTextToUserAfterTimeResultBeingSaved" />
    </camel:route>
</camelContext>
```